# Is it possible to use regular expressions (or more general templates) to define variables?

Tags: python, regex, templates, pattern-matching

Let us consider the following template:

```
*aaa*bbb*
```

It should return all strings that contain `aaa` as well as `bbb` as sub-strings (with the restriction that `bbb` comes after `aaa`).

What I want to have is a possibility to use sub-strings that are (1) before `aaa`, (2) between `aaa` and `bbb` as well as (3) after `bbb` (some of these sub-strings could be empty). So, basically I want to know what stand behind each star. In more details, I want to use these three sub-strings to construct a new string (output).

For example I might want to interchange the first and the second sub-strings, put `ccc` between them and remove the last sub-string (as well as `aaa` and `bbb`). What I want to do can be expressed in the following more formal way:

```
{?x1}aaa{?x2}bbb{?x3} -> {?x2}ccc{?x1}
```

Note that I have replaced `*` by `{?x1}`, `{?x2}` and `{?x1}`. In this way I define three variables that I use later.

For example, if I have `XXXaaaYYYbbbZZZ` as input, I should generate the following string as output: `YYYcccXXX`

**ADDED**

My question is if there is a flexible template language that also allows to defined "variables" (parts of the original input sequence that can be use to define a new output sequence). I should probably add that I need a Python solution.

Comment: @anubhava, I have corrected my question.

Comment: Sounds like you want references, which are part of most regular expression libraries, including Python's.  E.g. `re.sub("(.*)aaa(.*)bbb(.*)", r"\2ccc\1", "XXXaaaYYYbbbZZZ")`.

Comment: @jpkotta, thank you. It is exactly what I needed! By the way, why you didn't post it as an answer (instead of comment)?

Comment: I wasn't quite sure if that's what you were asking.  Added as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you want references, which are part of most regular expression libraries, including Python's.

```
ccc_str = re.sub("(.*)aaa(.*)bbb(.*)", r"\2ccc\1", "XXXaaaYYYbbbZZZ")
```